# Sum of Factor Pairs in Arithmetic Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

I'm analyzing integer numbers with factor pair sums forming an arithmetic sequence.
E.g., the number 27720 allows to build the arithmetic sequence 334..338..342..346 :

27720 = 154 x 180  and    154+180=334

27720 = 140 x 198  and    140+198=338

27720 = 132 x 210  and    132+210= 342

27720 = 126 x 220  and    126+220=346

It seems difficult to find integer numbers with longer sequences of this type.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be more of a response than an "answer" (I suspect if there were a well-understood solution for the implied problem, someone would have already posted it.)  I see this as yet another example of how  addition "doesn't play well together" with multiplication; if they did, a lot of number-theoretic conjectures would have been resolved long ago...

The integer in your example is $ \ 27720 \ = \ 2^3·3^2·5·7·11 \ \ , \ $ for which $ \ \sqrt{27720} \ \approx \ 166.5 \ \ . \ $  If we write out its divisors, "folding back on themselves" those which are closest to the square-root of the number, we have

[image]

Each of the pairs of divisors you found are marked in a particular color.  They "partition" the factors as:

$$  154 · 180 \ \ = \ \ (2·7·11) \ · \ (2^2·3^2·5) \ \ \ , \ \ \ 140 · 198 \ \ = \ \ (2^2·5·7) \ · \ (2 ·3^2·11) \ \ \ ,  $$
$$  132 · 210 \ \ = \ \ (2^2·3·11) \ · \ (2·3·5·7) \ \ \ , \ \ \ 126 · 220 \ \ = \ \ (2·3^2·7) \ · \ (2^2 ·5·11) \ \ \ .  $$

A search among divisors "near" the square-root of the integer seems more fruitful, since the divisors greater that $ \ \sqrt{N} \ $ "spread out" more and more "rapidly", making it less likely that sums of pairs of divisors will be uniformly-spaced, as we desire for arithmetic progressions.  (I won't say such progressions cannot occur -- I have not studied that issue exhaustively.)

So it appears that one wants to look at integers with *lots* of divisors for the best prospects of finding such progressions.  If we examine $ \ 2751840 \ = \ 2^5·3^3·5·7^2·13 \ \ , \ \ \sqrt{2751840} \ \approx \ 1658.9 \ \ , \ $ we find "in the vicinity" of $ \ 1659 \ \ : $

[image]

The arithmetic progression I located is $$ \ 1638 + 1680 \ = \ 3318 \ \ , \ \ 1512 + 1820 \ = \ 3332 \ \ , \ \ 1456 + 1890 \ = \ 3346 \ \ . \  $$
(There *may* be others, but none stood out to me while checking differences between divisor-pair sums.)

Testing an integer with a still larger number of prime factors - - $ \ 5054400 \ = \ 2^6·3^5·5^2·13 \ \ , $ $ \sqrt{5054400} \ \approx \ 2248.2 \ \  $ - - the divisors around the square-root are

[image]

In this case, I belatedly found an arithmetic progression, though not close to the square-root:

$$ \ 1350 + 3744 \ = \ 5094 \ \ , \ \ 1296 + 3900 \ = \ 5196 \ \ , \ \ 1248 + 4050 \ = \ 5298 \ \ . \  $$
[This was "edited into" the orginal illustration.]  It certainly does not appear to be easy to find arithmetic progressions of length greater than $ \ 3 \ . $  This example also makes clear that it isn't necessarily enough for an integer *merely* to have a lot of divisors.

What we are seeking to do is locate pairs of divisors of an integer $ \ N \ $ for which we have
$$ r  +  \frac{N}{r} \ = \ S \ \ , \ \ (r - \Delta_1)  +  \frac{N}{(r - \Delta_1)} \  =  \ S + d \ \ , \ \  (r - \Delta_2)  +  \frac{N}{(r - \Delta_2)} \  =  \ S + 2d \ \ , \ \ \ldots  $$

The difficulty in locating these progressions seems to lie in the fact that there is no simple relation among the $ \ \Delta_k \ \ $ that readily tells us how to determine the initial term of the progression, the common difference between its terms, or what divisor-pair we should "start" at in what integer.

It struck me as I was putting this post together that it might be worth looking at the [*highly composite* integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number)  , each of which has more divisors than any of the integers which precede it ( $ \ 27720 \ $ is on the list).  For $ \ 665280 \ = \ 2^6·3^3·5·7·11 \ \ , \ \ \sqrt{665280} \ \approx \ 815.6 \ \ , \ $ we note

[image]

Here, we still don't see any arithmetic progressions of length greater than $ \ 3 \ \ , \ $ but we *do* have ones which are consecutive and even *interleaved!*

$$ \ 792 + 840 \ = \ 1632 \ \ , \ \ 770 + 864 \ = \ 1634 \ \ , \ \ 756 + 880 \ = \ 1636 \ \ ;  $$
$$ \ 720 + 924 \ = \ 1644 \ \ , \ \ 693 + 960 \ = \ 1653 \ \ , \ \ 672 + 990 \ = \ 1662 \ \ ;  $$
$$ \ 756 + 880 \ = \ 1636 \ \ , \ \ 704 + 945 \ = \ 1649 \ \ , \ \ 672 + 990 \ = \ 1662 \ \ . \  $$
$$ \ 594 + 1120 \ = \ 1714 \ \ , \ \ 576 + 1155 \ = \ 1731 \ \ , \ \ 560 + 1188 \ = \ 1748 \ \ . \  $$

All this doesn't *answer* your question, but perhaps gives some sense of the depth of the problem.  I would certainly be interested in remarks by other people here.